# Python cannot import installed modules

Tags: python, command-line, pip, conda

I've been searching far and wide on google for that past week or so trying to figure out what the problem is, but I have had no luck. I've run into the same issue on two different computers both running Windows 10 64 bit. I had it working before I installed new SSDs into my computers.

I'm trying to run a python program but keep getting the import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salesman.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

And this goes for any module that I try to import. I've tried uninstalling/installing packages multiple times with both pip and conda. Conda will list the packages as installed, but pip will not. Pip keeps failing to build the wheel for the package. On my second computer, both pip and conda list the packages as installed. My system environment variables are correct as far as I know.

[My environment variables](https://i.gyazo.com/5e41289134cb7032c2cbc922f4ef7097.png)

[The list of packages seen by conda](https://i.gyazo.com/b70665f04e45c8c776488cdaa1a3feba.png)

[The list of packages seen by pip](https://i.gyazo.com/8bdc4f930de4ce918aa192b3230eee73.png)

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for the help in advance, greatly appreciated!

Comment: In case you're not doing so already, start working with [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html).

Comment: try import sys and run print sys.version and sys.path to figure out 1) python has been installed correctly and 2) where the interpreter is looking for the modules. Probably you have to set up the path.